# Show Guides and do snapping while dragging jquery draggable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

If there are multiple jquery draggable divs I want to see guides and snap to guides, edges and corners of others divs.

Here's the code:

```js
$(".draggable").draggable();
$(".draggable").resizable();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: courier new, courier;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.draggable {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: move;
  position: relative;
}

.guide {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#guide-h {
  border-top: 1px dashed #55f;
  width: 100%;
}

#guide-v {
  border-left: 1px dashed #55f;
  height: 100%;
}

#image{
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#image_h {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>


<div class="draggable">drag me!</div>
<div class="draggable">you can drag me too, if you like</div>
<div class="draggable">hep hep</div>
<div class="draggable" id="image">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/06/16/29/jay-5988657__340.jpg">
  <div id="image_h">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
<div id="guide-h" class="guide"></div>
<div id="guide-v" class="guide"></div>
```

The blue line in following image is what i want to be shown while divs are being dragged
[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2qtW.png). Divs should snap to the blue guiding lines when divs are aligned.

don't change the relative and absolute position of classes as I've used them to overlay one div on another.

I tried searching online but solutions are too old, awakward and work with jquery 2.x
Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The scope of this questions is maybe too large. jQuery UI does not have any of these features built in except for Snapping. It is not clear from the image what should generate the Guides or how they should work. It may be best to break this down into small single issues and then present each as you need help.

Answer (score 1):

To address the first part of your question, you can manage the guides like so.

```js
$(function() {
  function moveGuides(top, left) {
    $("#guide-h").css("top", top + "px");
    $("#guide-v").css("left", left + "px");
  }

  function getMyCorners(el) {
    var p = $(el).position();
    return {
      top: p.top,
      left: p.left,
      bottom: p.top + $(el).height(),
      right: p.left + $(el).width()
    };
  }

  function startGuides(targetEl) {
    var c = getMyCorners(targetEl);
    moveGuides(c.top, c.right);
    $(".guide").show();
  }

  function stopGuides() {
    $(".guide").hide();
  }

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    start: function(e, ui) {
      startGuides(this);
    },
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      var c = getMyCorners(this);
      moveGuides(c.top, c.right);
    },
    stop: stopGuides
  });
  $(".draggable").resizable({
    start: function(e, ui) {
      startGuides(this);
    },
    resize: function(e, ui) {
      var c = getMyCorners(this);
      moveGuides(c.top, c.right);
    },
    stop: stopGuides
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: courier new, courier;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.draggable {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: move;
  position: relative;
}

.guide {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#guide-h {
  border-top: 1px dashed #55f;
  width: 100%;
}

#guide-v {
  border-left: 1px dashed #55f;
  height: 100%;
}

#image {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#image_h {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />


<div class="draggable">drag me!</div>
<div class="draggable">you can drag me too, if you like</div>
<div class="draggable">hep hep</div>
<div class="draggable" id="image">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/06/16/29/jay-5988657__340.jpg">
  <div id="image_h">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
<div id="guide-h" class="guide"></div>
<div id="guide-v" class="guide"></div>
```

With helper functions, you can reveal the guides, and move them based on specific events.

The next, and much more involved portion, would be to create collision detection for the various elements. This will require checking against each of the elements involved against all the other elements. For example:

```
if($("#guide-h").position().top == $(".draggable").position().top){
  // Stop event
}
```

I am guessing that you are looking to create alignment. So when a Guide collides with an edge, it should prevent the User from dragging or resizing the element further in that direction. Also, do you want it to Snap and what tolerance should that snap be?

Since you did not provide those details, I am not really able to address your second question in full.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you but if I drag the boxes below a certain point on page the vertical guides are cut out and not shown properly and yes I want the guides to snap to box's edges. The snapping distance should be 5px. [Refer to this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7uMh/103/), I want the guides and snapping to be like that

Comment: @SomeNerd if that is the case, you will want to adjust the `top` of the vertical guide when `scroll` event happens.

Comment: @SomeNerd the example you shared creates a Guide based on other elements and not the element being dragged. Looking at the code, it seems like it would move to jQuery 3.4.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.1 without issue. See: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zkuadgyf/

Comment: will do the adjustment for `top` of the vertical guide when `scroll` event happens and also can you add snapping feature in your answer, keep snapping distance 5px. we are almost there!

Comment: I gave the jsfiddle example just for reference. It uses absolute positioning for draggable objects. If I change it then example doesn't seem to work properly. I want to be able to keep any type of positioning and not affect the behaviour of draggable divs also when we move to jQuery 3.4.1 the div jumps to start of it under cursor while dragging starts